# HOW: import Scanned data from an ID into text boxes on separate view IOS (BLINKID)

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode-scanner, blink

I am developing an app for a project that takes data from a scanned USDL (Using BlinkID) and inputs data such as: First Name, Last Name, Middle Name, DOB, Sex, and address into seperate text boxes on a separate view controller. Then when hitting "OK" takes them to another view controller with other options that I will be creating.

I am stuck though. I can't seem to transfer the data from scanned USDL into text boxes on a separate View Controller. I am able to import the data into Xcode when scanned, but I want to be able to switch views automatically after scan and have the app auto fill the textboxes labeled: FIRST NAME, LAST NAME, ADDRESS, DOB, SEX, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following steps:

- Start with BlinkID-sample app from [Github](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-ios/tree/master/Samples/BlinkID-sample).
- Create a new view controller (let's call it `USDLResultController`) where you want the results to be presented. Add text boxes to that view controller and implement the whole UI
- Add a public property to `USDLResultController` (in the header file) as follows:

  `@property (nonatomic, strong) PPUsdlRecognizerResult *usdlRecognizerResult;`
- In the view controller which calls the scanning, in the callback where you receive the scanning result (typically it's `scanningViewController:didOutputResults:`), check if you received an USDL recognizer result
- If you received it, instantiate `USDLResultController` (either from storyboard, either in code), and set the `usdlRecognizerResult` to the result you received
- In `viewWillAppear` (or some other similar method) of the `USDLResultController` populate the text boxes with values from `usdlRecognizerResult` property.

If you still need help after this, please send a link to the project where you're implementing this so we can take a look.

Disclaimer: I'm working for the BlinkID team.